# Displaying file name in Non-English Language for dynamic file download for Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I've develop a dynamic file download program in Struts2, which is allow users to download files stored on a database.

My problem is that, if the file name contains Non-English Language characters (in this case it's "Thai Characters"). The file name will be displayed as URL instead.

This is my JSP

```
<s:url id="urlTag" action="downloadAmsFile">
     <s:param name="index">1</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{urlTag}">Download</s:a>
```

This is my java code for result's parameters

```
setFilename(assetObj.getFileName());
setMimeType(assetObj.getContentType());
setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(assetObj.getBytes()));
```

This is my action

```
<action name="downloadAmsFile" class="com.title.ams.action.FileUploadAllAction" method="downloadAmsFile">   
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">%{contentType}</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=%{contentDisposition}</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>       
    </result>               
</action>
```

If I download a file with Non-English Language, the file name will be
"downloadAmsFile.action?index=1".

Comment: This is where you can use i18n.

Comment: @RomanC
Please provide some explanation or example.

Comment: i18n stands for internationalization, what is the problem?

Comment: @RomanC
I'm not sure if this is the case. I can display every thing correctly in both Thai and English, except for the file name in Thai language, which will be displayed as URL instead when they choose to "Save As".

Or should I add 
<s:param name="request_locale" >th</s:param>
as a parameter for the url.

Comment: Not sure in your case I would translate the name to the requested locale.

Comment: Does your container supports utf characters in url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
I have to convert file names to unicode.

```
String result = "";

    if (text != null) {
        StringBuilder ascii = new StringBuilder(text);
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            int code = (int)text.charAt(i);
            if ((0xE01<=code) && (code <= 0xE5B )){
                ascii.setCharAt( i, (char)(code - 0xD60));
            }
        }
       result = ascii.toString();
    }
    return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not likely going to be easy to solve. When using the stream result type, you are actually manipulating HTTP headers. For instance, the contentDisposition ends up being sent to the client as follows:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

From what I understand, it may be possible to send text in an encoding other than ISO-8859-1, but the question is whether or not clients (browsers) will support it. I think your best choice is to check the contentDisposition value in your struts action and if it is not latin-1 then maybe provide a default value that (hopefully) makes sense. Unfortunately, this is probably not a case where i18n can help since it has to do with munging http headers.